# Kotlin equivalent of ternary operator

Tags: ternary-operator, kotlin

So in java we have the ternary operator (?), which sometimes is useful to easy some value computed by a if-else inlines. For example:

```
myAdapter.setAdapterItems(
            textToSearch.length == 0
            ? noteList
            : noteList.sublist(0, length-5)
)
```

I know the equivalent in kotlin would be:

```
myAdapter.setAdapterItems(
                if(textToSearch.length == 0)
                    noteList
                else
                    noteList.sublist(0, length-5) 
)
```

But i just used to love the ternary operator in Java, for short expression conditions, and when passing values to a method. Is there any Kotlin equivalent?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no ternary operator in Kotlin.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html

> In Kotlin, if is an expression, i.e. it returns a value. Therefore there is no ternary operator (condition ? then : else), because ordinary if works fine in this role.

You can find a more detailed explanation [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/ternary-operator/2116/4).

Comment: Not a big fan of this, tbh

Comment: Maybe it is to avoid confusion with `?:` and `?` followed by `:` ... but I miss having it.

Comment: @JaysonMinard I feel like being able to use `if` in an infix form would take away much of the boilerplate.

Comment: @KirillRakhman
@JaysonMinard

Something like this isn't _too_ unclear to me:
`(textToSearch.length == 0) +noteList -noteList.sublist(0, length-5)`  
  
I implemented it like this: https://gist.github.com/Jire/46b1ee35855a5e97bfd5

Comment: The decision to use `if...else` as an expression probably goes along with the decision to use `when` (similar to switch) as an expression. But I think that replacing `a ? b : c` with `if(a) b else c` goes against the goal to make Kotlin more concise and readable then Java.

Comment: I think `Array<Array<etc.>>` also goes against that goal - luckily for some reason I don't use arrays nearly as much as I used to. but every time I have to type `if() else` I get annoyed.. usually because I want to insert it into areas that verbosity is very undesirable