# Why doesn't Kotlin support "ternary operator"

Tags: ternary-operator, kotlin

Explain: This question is more about the design intentions of Kotlin. Many expression languages support both `Ternary operator` and `if expression` [e.g., *Ruby, Groovy*.]

---

First of all, I know Groovy supports both `Ternary operator` and `Elvis operator`: [Ternary operator in Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_ternary_operator). So I don't think it's a syntax problem.

---

Then the official documents said:

> In Kotlin, if is an expression, i.e. it returns a value. Therefore there is no ternary operator (condition ? then : else), because ordinary if works fine in this role.

And this doesn't convince me. Because Kotlin support `Elvis operator` which ordinary if works just fine in that role either.

I think `ternary operator` is sometimes better than ordinary `if`, though I wonder why doesn't Kotlin just support `ternary operator`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin Ternary Conditional Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336500/kotlin-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: Also duplicate of the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935918/kotlin-equivalent-of-ternary-operator

Answer (score 4):

In languages which have `ternary operator` you use it like this

```
String value = condition ? foo : bar;
```

In Kotlin you can do the same thing using if and else

```
var value = if(condition) foo else bar;
```

Its bit verbose than the `ternary operator`. But designers of Kotlin have thought it is ok. You can use `if-else` like this because in Kotlin `if` is an expression and returns a value

`Elvis operator` is essentially a compressed version of ternary conditional statement and equivalent to following in Kotlin.

```
var value = if(foo != null) foo else bar;
```

But if `Elvis operator` is used it simplify as follows

```
var value = foo ?: bar;
```

This is considerable simplification and Kotlin decided to keep it.

Answer (score 2):

Because `if .. else ..` works fine. Take a look:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var i = 2

    println("i ${ if(i == 1) "equals 1" else "not equals 1" }")
}
```

Comment: `if-else` works fine in many languages and they have ternary operator too ([look at Ruby](https://gist.github.com/maxd/76e924d147d60cdc003c) for example).

Comment: I just wrote that Andrey Breslav (one of the authors of Kotlin) said in his video presentations in russian. i.e. "if else is fine, no needs of ternary operator"

Comment: Right, but this is very doubtful argument (like extension methods is useless because exists "utility" classes but extension methods is exists in Kotlin). Except this argument I don't see real motivation why they can't implement ternary operator because ternary operators is a syntax sugar like extension methods.

Comment: Are the referenced video presentations in Russian available online? If so, where can I find them? Thanks.

Comment: I saw video from this post https://habrahabr.ru/company/jugru/blog/278647/ I'm not sure about which one of them contains phrase about ternary operator

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator has its problems, for example it is hard to read with big expressions. Here is a line from my C++ project where I used ternary operator:

```
const long offset = (comm_rank > 0) ? task_size_mod + (comm_rank - 1) * task_size : 0;
```

I would rather use an `if else` expression here since it is so much more visible.

Answering you question, I am aware of two reasons why `ternary operator` was not implemented in Kotlin:

1) Since `if else` is an expression anyway, it can replace `? :`

2) Experience from other languages (C++) shows that `? :` provokes hard-to-read code, so it is better to be left out

Comment: Here is `if-else` instead of ternary operator: `const long offset = if (comm_rank > 0) task_size_mod + (comm_rank - 1) * task_size else 0;` -  it is still a big expression :) Just need to use ternary operators for simple conditions and `if-else` (in multi-line variant) in other cases (as in your case). Moreover, in some cases ternary operator has better "readability" than `if-else` because it shorter.

Comment: @maxd If I had `if-else` here I would split it into 4 lines. For `? :` it is considered a nonsense

Answer (score -1):

Programmers at some point, have to make a decision to execute a block of code, this is known as **Control Flow**. **If** statement is most basic way to control flow in **Kotlin**. Important point to note that  in **Kotlin**, **If** is an **expression** not a **statement** as it is **Java**.

1. **Statement**: A statement is an executed line which does not return a
   value. As a result, statement cannot sit right side of an equal
   sign.
2. Expression: An expression returns a value.So the result of a Kolin
   If expression can be assigned to a variable.

   **Because of this the ternary expression would be redundant and does not exists in Kotlin. In Java we would write** (Here is the answer of your question)

## For Example

**Ternary Operator in Java**

int lowest  = (a < b) ? a : b;

In **Kotlin** we can write something similar using the if expression.

val lowest = if(a < b) a else b

NOTE:
When If is used as an expression it must contain an else clause. The expression must have a value in all case.

Answer (score -3):

Because **if-else** is an expression in Kotlin :

```
String check = number % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd" // Java

if (number % 2 == 0) "even else "odd" // Kotlin
```

So that's why there are no ternary operator in Kotlin, Moreover you can use `when` expressions too, it's so handy if you want to provide a lot of possible execution paths